# How do i compute the dot product of n tensors by n vectors with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, dot-product

I want to compute the product of  N tensors with N vectors. I am sure there is an easy numpyic way of doing so but I didn't succeed thinking of one.
essentially I have tensors ndarray of shape (N, k, k) and vectors ndarray of shape (N, K) and I want to calculate the array A of shape (N, k) s.t `A[i] = tensors[i].dot(vecotrs[i].reshape(-1, 1))`

In my specific case k = 3 but I don't think it should matter.

Is there a simple way of doing so with numpy?

Comment: Is the output `k` meant to match the first or the second `k` of the first input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using [`np.einsum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
np.einsum('ijk,il->ij', a, b)
```

or:

```
np.einsum('ijk,il->ik', a, b)
```

depending on which index you actually meant the sum to be computed (right now it is ambiguous).